# creating curves using JFreechart

Tags: java, sql, dataset, jfreechart

i am trying to make curves using `JFreeChart`  but i well get the values from a Database. i used this code to create one but i got an erreur in this line `datset.executeQuery(rqt);` i can not undrestand what is wrong exactly so if anyone could tell me i will be grateful here is the code that i used

```
try {
            String rqt = "SELECT `poste`,`S1` FROM `allin` "; 
            JDBCCategoryDataset datset;
            datset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(connection());
            if (con != null) {
                System.out.println("connect");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" not connect");

            }
            datset.executeQuery(rqt);
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Data", "X", "Y", datset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
            if (chart != null) {
                System.out.println("done");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" not done");

            }
            BarRenderer rend = null;
            CategoryPlot plot = null;
            rend = new BarRenderer();
            ChartPanel cPanel;
            cPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            cPanel.setBackground(new Color(54, 63, 73));
            Chartpanel.add(cPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Chartpanel.validate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Courbes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Some examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20JDBCCategoryDataset).

Comment: thank you i have foun out what was wrong the code is correct but i have imported the wrong jar file